# Portlet preferences scope in a Liferay configuration page

Tags: scope, liferay, portlet, preference

I develop a Liferay portlet which has preferences unique per layout: preferences are specific to each portlet window, and users can modify them through "Preferences" option (Edit mode).

In liferay-portlet.xml:

```
<preferences-unique-per-layout>true</preferences-unique-per-layout>
```

However i would like to add a configuration page, in order to manage global parameters which should be shared across all portlet windows. Currently these parameters are handled as "init-param" in portlet.xml but it is not very convenient, admin users should be able to change those parameters through portal UI.

I followed the approach described [here](https://www.liferay.com/fr/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Add+Config+Page+to+Plugin+Portlet) to create a such page, it works for the current portlet window but preferences are not shared. Is it possible to use a specific scope for some preferences? This [other wiki](https://www.liferay.com/fr/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/How+to+Add+a+Configuration+Page+to+a+Portlet) makes use of a method specifying "uniquePerLayout" and "uniquePerGroup" but i did not find this method in APIs from 5.2.3 to 6.2

```
public static PortletPreferences getPortletSetup(
      ActionRequest req, 
      String portletId, 
      boolean uniquePerLayout,
      boolean uniquePerGroup)
```

Please could someone enlighten me on this subject?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In 6.2, There is getPortletSetup method that accept layout and group,

> PortletPreferencesFactoryUtil.getPortletSetup(scopeGroupId, layout,
>   portletId, defaultPreferences).

You can get scopeGroupId, layout from themeDisplay as below and portletId & defaultPreferences should be set as per your requirement.

> ```
>     ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
>     Layout layout = LayoutLocalServiceUtil.getLayout(themeDisplay.getPlid());
> ```